# Makefile: embed 'if' condition in 'foreach' loop

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to embed `if` condition `foreach` loop in makefile.

```
COMP1 := 1

COMP2 := KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK


define dir_rule_template
        $(info $(1))
endef

$(foreach compdir,hello hai how are you, \
    $(ifdef COMP1 , $(eval $(call dir_rule_template,$(COMP1)/$(compdir))), $(eval $(call dir_rule_template,$(COMP2)/$(compdir)))))
```

Output:-

```
testuser@system-linux-test:~/debug_test/new_make_client$ make -f test.mk
1/hello
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK/hello
1/hai
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK/hai
1/how
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK/how
1/are
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK/are
1/you
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK/you
make: *** No targets.  Stop.
```

Here i am expecting only :-

```
1/hello
1/hai
1/how
1/are
1/you
```

Am I doing something wrong here? if `COMP1` is defined, I don't want to go to latter `eval` statement. I thought the latter one should be treated as `else` part. Please advice!

Comment: Or you can use the `$(if ...)` function.

Comment: could you please help with snippet, I tried `if` as well. But same result.

Comment: You can't use `$(if COMP1,...` because `COMP1` is a static string.  It's always true.  You have to use `$(if $(COMP1),...` so you check the _value_ of the _variable_ `COMP1` to see if it's set or if it's empty.  See the answer by Beta.

Answer (score 0):

The conditional `ifdef` is not a function, so it can't be easily combined with the `foreach` function.

But you can put it in the template:

```
define template
ifdef COMP1
$$(info $(COMP1)/$(1))
else
$$(info $(COMP2)/$(1))
endif
endef

$(foreach compdir,hello hai how are you, \
$(eval $(call template,$(compdir))))
```

**EDIT:** It still isn't clear exactly what you are trying to do, but if you can use the `if` function as @MadScientist suggests, then a cleaner solution is possible:

```
$(foreach compdir,hello hai how are you,\
$(info $(if $(COMP1),$(COMP1),$(COMP2))/$(compdir)))
```

Comment: I just posted a sample one. But my original snippet is bit complex. Where i have to only embed `if` check in `foreach` loop.